# Why I always get Bad Request 400 from Amazon Advertising API?

Tags: delphi, soap, amazon-web-services

I have delphi application using Amazon Advertising API.
When I try to get ItemSearch the I always get HTTP error 400 Bad Request.

Where is the point?

My request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Timestamp>2014-01-13T15:28:52Z</SOAP-ENV:Timestamp>
    <SOAP-ENV:AWSAccessKeyId>MYACCESSKEYID</SOAP-ENV:AWSAccessKeyId>
    <SOAP-ENV:Signature>rzNprsyKGKN2J4JZ8b/GvHqYPqs+kTJe0O5bjdnvHV8=</SOAP-ENV:Signature>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ItemSearch xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
        <AWSAccessKeyId>MYACCESSKEYID</AWSAccessKeyId>
        <Request>
             <Keywords>Harry</Keywords>
             <SearchIndex>All</SearchIndex>
        </Request>
     </ItemSearch>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I create the signature so:

```
ts := '2014-01-13T15:28:52Z';
sig := GetBase64_HMAC_SHA256(MYSECRETKEY, 'ItemSearch' + ts);
```

Amazon SOAP URL I use:

```
rio.URL := 'https://webservices.amazon.de/onca/soap?Service=AWSECommerceService';
```

**UPDATE:**

My delphi code:

```
Cred := TSOAPCredentials.Create;
rio := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
rio.OnAfterExecute := HTTPRIOAfterExecute;
rio.OnBeforeExecute := HTTPRIOBeforeExecute;
rio.SOAPHeaders.Send(cred);

rio.URL := 'https://webservices.amazon.com/onca/soap?Service=AWSECommerceService';

req := ItemSearchRequest.Create;
req.SearchIndex := 'All';
req.Keywords := 'Harry';
SetLength(ss, 1);
ss[0] := 'Small';
req.ResponseGroup := ss;
SetLength(reqs, 1);
reqs[0] := req;


isearch := ItemSearch.Create;
isearch.AWSAccessKeyId := MYACCESSKEYID;
isearch.Request := reqs;

res := GetAWSECommerceServicePortType(false, '', rio).ItemSearch(isearch);
```

Comment: Thanks Mason, I got little bit crazy after a day with the error.

Comment: Can you modify your code to get soap fault as well. I tried this api with your configuration using soap ui and i am getting error as soap fault "The request must contain the parameter Signature." so i tried sending request as mentioned in my answer and guess what, i am getting  response like your time stamp is expired or your access key is not valid somethings like these messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
<soap:Header
  xmlns:aws="http://security.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/">
  <aws:AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE</aws:AWSAccessKeyId>
  <aws:Timestamp>2008-02-10T23:59:59Z</aws:Timestamp>
  <aws:Signature>SZf1CHmQnrZbsrC13hCZS061ywsEXAMPLE</aws:Signature>
</soap:Header>
```

Your header should be look like above. I don't know what would be "aws" in your case.

And in your delphi code, rio.URL is different from soap URL, which you have mentioned in your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I went to REST format. Soap was not working too long.